# What happened to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$?

Tags: calculus, probability, normal-distribution, expectation

I'm doing the following exercise:

[image]

I understand it until they do the substitution. Since $\varphi(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}$, where did the constant go in the exercise when they did the substitution? Also, how did they do the "jump" to the last equation?

I would be very grateful if someone could help me understand it.

Comment: The calculation of the integral $$\int ze^{-z^2/2}$$ is simply done without the constant but you can add it and nothing will change. In the last step we simply use the previously calculated integral... Basically:
$$\int_t^\infty z\varphi(z)dz=-\varphi(z)\Big|_{t}^\infty=\varphi(t)$$

Comment: It's replace back to $\varphi$ after the integral. While doing the integral, you don't to make the expression messier with an irrelevant constant.

Comment: To evaluate $\int af(x)\,{\rm d}x$ we might as well evaluate $\int f(x)\,{\rm d}x$ then multiply by $a$, is the idea.

Comment: Not sure why the two downvotes... anyway thank you very much all, got it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They dropped the constant when they did the substitution because if you can integrate $ \int \; z e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}} \; \; dz $ then you can integrate any constant multiple of it which is what $ \int \; z \phi(z) \; \; dz$ would be.

For the first part of the last inequality, they are using the fact that if $A$ is any event and I is the indicator random variable for $A$, then $P(A) = E( I(A) )$.

In the last inequality, they are using the above fact for the event $Z > t$:

$P(Z > t) = E(I(Z>t))$

The second part of the last inequality come from the inequality they establish earlier:

$E(I(Z>t)) \leq \frac{1}{t} \int_t^\infty z \phi(z) \; dz$

Then you would just need to compute the integral $\frac{1}{t} \int_t^\infty z \phi(z) \; dz$.

$$\frac{1}{t} \int_t^\infty z \phi(z) \; dz$$

$$\frac{1}{t} \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_t^b z \phi(z) \; dz$$

$$\frac{1}{t} \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_t^b z \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}} \; dz$$

$$\frac{1}{t} \lim_{b \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_t^b z e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}} \; dz$$

$$\frac{1}{t} \lim_{b \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \left [ -e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}} \right ]_t^b$$

$$\frac{1}{t} \lim_{b \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \left [ -e^{-\frac{b^2}{2}} - \left ( -e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} \right ) \right ]$$

$$\frac{1}{t} \lim_{b \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \left [ -e^{-\frac{b^2}{2}} + e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} \right ]$$

$$\frac{1}{t} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} $$

$$\frac{1}{t} \phi(t)$$

Comment: That's a very detailed answer, I accepted it as the final one and wish I could give +1 but don't have 15 rep yet.

Comment: @slazien now you have.